# We can access server variable in asp like Request.ServerVariable() , is there any similar approach available in NodeJS and express

Tags: node.js, express

We are passing server variables from SSO server to client. I need to fetch those details in NodeJS and Express server. Is it possible?

Comment: Try to make your question title more precise and provide details in question description

Comment: A similar approach is `req` object.

Comment: Which parameter in req object